# Piping sed to cat via xargs?

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I have three files like this:

```
haeder
line
```

I write this:

```
sed '1,1d' */*filename*.txt | xarg cat > crap4.txt
```

and expect this:

```
line
line
line
```

but I get "cat: line: No such file or directory"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -s '1d' */*filename*.txt > crap4.txt
```

The `-s` switch treats each file separately rather than the default which is as one continuous stream.

Answer (score 2):

That's because sed is sending the *contents* of those edited files out.  The first argument cat gets is the first line of the edited file.

You're making it too complicated, you want

```
sed '1,1d' */*filename*.txt > crap4.txt
```

Comment: I get "header" from file 2 and 3 into crap4.txt.

Answer (score 1):

This is a useless use of cat (as defined by Randal Schwartz).  Using plain redirection works.  If you really wanted to use cat, you'd want to remove 'xargs' and use '-' as an argument to cat.  Here's an example to print all of the names from /etc/hosts

```
myhost> awk '{print $NF}' /etc/hosts | cat -
localhost
myhost

hosts
ip6-loopback
ip6-localnet
ip6-mcastprefix
ip6-allnodes
ip6-allrouters
ip6-allhosts
```

But using '>' instead and getting rid of the 'cat' is probably your best choice here.

Comment: "awk '{(getline); print $NF}' *filename*.txt | cat > crap.txt" worked

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked perfectly:

```
array=(*somestring*.txt)
for i in {0..2}; do
sed '1d' ${array[$i]} >> crap4.txt;
done
```

Bash to the rescue.

Thanx for the help.